# Adding records into table while running the db init

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using flask,sqlalchemy,sqlite and python for my application. When I run the db init for creating the database I want some default set of values hase to be added into the database. I have tried these two things to add the records into the table. One method is using 'event'.

```
from sqlalchemy.event import listen
from sqlalchemy import event, DDL

@event.listens_for(studentStatus.__table__, 'after_create')
def insert_initial_values(*args, **kwargs):
    db.session.add(studentStatus(status_name='Waiting on admission'))
    db.session.add(studentStatus(status_name='Waiting on student'))
    db.session.add(studentStatus(status_name='Interaction Initiated'))
    db.session.commit()
```

When I run

```
python manage_db.py db init,
python manage_db.py db migrate,
python manage_db.py db upgrade
```

I didnt get any issues but the records are not getting created.

The another method I tried is ,in the models.py I have included

```
record_for_student_status = studentStatus(status_name="Waiting on student")
db.session.add(record_for_student_status)
db.session.commit()
print(record_for_student_status)
```

The Class Model code:

```
class StudentStatus(db.Model): 
   status_id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True) 
   status_name = db.Column(db.String) 
   def __repr__(self): 
      return f"studentStatus('{self.status_id}','{self.status_name}')"
```

When I run python manage_db.py db init ,I am getting an error Student_status,there is no such table.

Can some one help me how to add the default values to the student_status table when I run db init?

I have tried with flask-seeder also. I have installed flask seeder nd added one new file called seeds.py and I ran the flask seed run

My seeds.py looks like this

```
class studentStatus(db.Model):
  def __init__(self, status_id=None, status_name=None):
    self.status_id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    self.status_name = db.Column(db.String,status_name) 

  def __str__(self):
    return "ID=%d, Name=%s" % (self.status_id, self.status_name)



class DemoSeeder(Seeder):

  # run() will be called by Flask-Seeder
  def run(self):
    # Create a new Faker and tell it how to create User objects
    faker = Faker(
      cls=studentStatus,
      init={
        "status_id": 1,
        "name": "Waiting on Admission"

      }
    )

    # Create 5 users
    for user in faker.create(5):
      print("Adding user: %s" % user)
      self.db.session.add(user)
```

I ran db init,db migrate and db upgrade. I didnt get any issues. When I ran flask seed run I am getting this error

```
Error: Could not locate a Flask application. You did not provide the "FLASK_APP" environment variable, and a "wsgi.py" or "app.py" module was not found in the current directory
```

I googled it and i tried 
export FLASK_APP=seeds.py

````
Then I ran the flask seed run ,I am getting an error ``` error could not import seeds.py```
Please help me in this.
What I need finally is when I do db initialization for the first time some default value have to be added to the database.
````

Answer (score 1):

Before running the flask application you should instantiate the FLASK_APP and FLASK_ENV.

First Create a function for adding data. assume that the function name is run like yours,

```
def run(self):
    # Create a new Faker and tell it how to create User objects
    faker = Faker(
      cls=studentStatus,
      init={
        "status_id": 1,
        "name": "Waiting on Admission"

      }
    )

    # Create 5 users
    for user in faker.create(5):
      print("Adding user: %s" % user)
      self.db.session.add(user)
```

Now you can call this function in the app running file. Assume that my file has named as app.py.

```
from application import app
if __name__ == '__main__':
     run()
     app.run(debug=True)
```

Now set the FLASK_APP and FLASK_ENV like below.

```
export FLASK_APP=app.py
export FLASK_ENV=development
```

After that, you can run the below commands.

```
flask db init
flask db  migrate
flask db upgrade
```

this will create all the tables and the data what you want.

For more details, you can get from the below link. This link is for a Github repository. There I have done adding some data when app initiating. Just read the readme.MD then you can get some more insight about setting up the FLASK_APP.

[Flask Data Adding when DB instantiating](https://github.com/SandaruThilakarathne/Highchart-Flask-Application/tree/master/Backend)

Comment: Hi Theesh, I have added the Flask_env and flask_app and then I start running the init and migration. I am not getting any error. I tried running the flask seed run also ,I am not getting any error now . But data is not getting inserted into the database.

Answer (score 0):

humm, seems like you put a underscore in `Student_status`, try to remove it. And other thing, try to write your class in CamelCase, is more "Pythonic" way to write a code, when you run it, the SQLalchemy will transform this class name to student_status table automatically

Comment: Hi Caio Filus,I have tried all the changes you have mentioned. But I am getting same error.

Comment: Yes My model code is                                                                                       
       class studentStatus(db.Model):
    "Save the status list"
    status_id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    status_name = db.Column(db.String)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"studentStatus('{self.status_id}','{self.status_name}')"